# Display corresponding values consistently if TRUE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have list of attachments. There are 18 possible attachments and each is checked for TRUE in J column, if so then Attachment name is displayed with formula:

```
=IF('Other Data'!J1=TRUE;'Other Data'!K1;"")
=IF('Other Data'!J2=TRUE;'Other Data'!K2;"")
=IF('Other Data'!J3=TRUE;'Other Data'!K3;"")
=IF('Other Data'!J4=TRUE;'Other Data'!K4;"")
etc...
```

The problem is that if there is a lot of FALSE values, there is a lot of empty spaces. Is it possible to display TRUE values one after each other without gaps?

[image]

Comment: Try use pivot table to summarize your data and use the filter TRUE in your Column J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the other option is that `J` values are `FALSE`?

If so, and you want to use formulas instead of a pivot table or powerquery for example, then:

[image]

Formula in `M1`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($K$1:$K$18,AGGREGATE(15,3,($J$1:$J$18=TRUE)*ROW($J$1:$J$18),COUNTIF($J$1:$J$18,FALSE)+ROW(A1))),"")
```

Drag down...

Pls never mind my Dutch Excel, `WAAR`=`TRUE` and `ONWAAR`=`FALSE`